# How to POST a request with user data with Alamofire 5 in Swift 5

Tags: swift, alamofire

I thought that I could `POST` user data with the code below but it did not `POST` it to my database. I've looked up what to put with `Swift 5`, but it throws errors up if I add more. What other code should I add?

```swift
    @IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "username":usernameTxt.text!,
            "password":passwordTxt.text!,
            "email":emailTxt.text!,
            "fullname":fullnameTxt.text!
        ]

        AF.request(URL_USER_REGISTER,method: .post, parameters: parameters).response {response in

        print(response)


            }
        }
```

url for first user: `localhost/testingapp/register.php?username=Sean&password=123@email=test@test.com&fullname=SeanO'Neal`

url in Xcode `let URL_USER_REGISTER = "localhost/testingapp/register.php"`

Comment: How did you get parameters from backend.? formData or row?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha yes I already made the first account through the search bar. in a row in the search bar

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is encoding type.Add preferred encoding type.
if you are are getting parameters through **form data**

```
encoding: URLEncoding.default
```

gettting parameters through row data as json

```
encoding: JSONEncoding.default
```

request like this,

```
AF.request(URL_USER_REGISTER
 ,method: .get,
 parameters: parameters,
 encoding: URLEncoding.default
 ).response {response in

    print(response)


    }
}
```

make sure your project allow **http** requests in info.plist  and use **http://192....** instead of **localhost** in AF request
[image: info.plist file]

Comment: It is still not show in my database. The first account worked when I typed it in the url  to localhost.

Comment: you can look it using  print(response).

Comment: can you add your first try ? how did you do that using type in url

Comment: Bro, seems it is GET request.not POST

Comment: It still didn't go threw. :(

Comment: bro check now.allow http calls in project

Comment: Thank you for your help. the reason was that you can't use localhost, you have to use the IP. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! you can not use localhost in your url. You have to use your IP.
to find it go to terminal and type `ifconfig` the it will be near the top where it says `inet`